# How to replace carriage returns and convert unix returns to windows returns in python?

Tags: python, excel, unix, export-to-csv, carriage-return

I am trying to compare to identical database using winmerge.

The tables contain a sample of the following information

| PV Module Certificate: Licensee/Certificate Holder Account | Model Number/s | PV Module Certificate: CEC Approved Date | PV Module Certificate: Expiry Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AE Alternative Energy GmbH | AE275P6-60 | 2019-10-10 | 2022-10-10 |
| AE Alternative Energy GmbH | AE280P6-60 | 2019-10-10 | 2022-10-10 |
| AE Alternative Energy GmbH | AE285HP6-60 | 2019-10-10 | 2022-10-10 |
| AE Alternative Energy GmbH | AE285P6-60 | 2019-10-10 | 2022-10-10 |
| AE Alternative Energy GmbH | AE290HP6-60 | 2019-10-10 | 2022-10-10 |

I apply some sorting and cleaning in python:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\pvmodules+_210416.csv")
df1= df1.sort_values(["PV Module Certificate: Licensee/Certificate Holder Account", "Model Number/s"], ascending= [True,True])
df1['PV Module Certificate: Expiry Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['PV Module Certificate: Expiry Date'])
df1['PV Module Certificate: CEC Approved Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['PV Module Certificate: CEC Approved Date'])
df1.to_csv(r'C:\Users\sortedmodules.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

However, the exported .csv is converted to unix format. I do the same cleaning in excel. The output .csv is in windows format.
I tried to compare the two outputs, which should be identical. But they do not compare as the carriage returns are different.
[image]

Attempting to convert the format from unix  to windows, i followed the steps shown in the following link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obqYfwzR-bQ
I open the list in notepad++, and replaced \n with \r\n.  Then from edit menu I conducted end of line conversion to windows format.
Below, I have shown two csv files being compared. In the first, the left table is sorted in excel, and the right in python ODE.[image: comparing the same file in excel and in python].

**They should be identical.**

Now, I try to export the csv by attempting to convert from unix to windows

```
df_SHW2.to_csv(r'/content/Approved_Active_Solar_Hotwater_convertion.csv', index=False, header=True, line_terminator="\r\n")
```

And that does not help.

When I compare this result with a csv exported with

```
df_SHW.to_csv(r'/content/Approved_Active_Solar_Hotwater.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

They are identical in comaprison as seen below.
[image]

**However, the problem is, df_SHW2 should give me identical csvs with when I sorted the csv in excel and saved it. All these contain the exact same information.**

There are some carriage returns conversion discussed in stackoverflow, but the problems are different to what is asked in this post.

How to replace carriage returns in python, so that a table sorted in excel and in python will have same output formats (both windows), and a comparison between the two should be identical?
I have attached a figure showing what is an ideal winmerge comparison.[image: An ideal comparison result]

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to instruct pandas to use correct carriage returns when creating output csv.
Set `line_terminator` to `\r\n` explicitly.

```
df1.to_csv(r'C:\Users\sortedmodules.csv', index=False, header=True, line_terminator="\r\n")
```

read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=line_terminator

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind suggestion @mojeto. This did not solve the issue of windows and unix difference. The result is same when I am comparing python sorted csv outputs. Bit even for the same processing done in excel, the outputs are not same. I have edited the post to include two images. The first one shows when two same csv's are compared, the only difference being one sorted in excel and other in python ODE. the second one shows the comparison between two python sorted csvs. One with line terminator and eithout line terminator

Comment: I see you saved `df_SHW2` using explicit `\r\n` and `df_SHW` using OS default and WinMerge says there is no difference. This makes me think the line terminator isn't an issue any more. By looking into original WinMerge result content of those lines doesn't match. The actual problem may be that excel produces different order than python script. Can you check your data line by line to see they are in the same order? @Dr.Islam